# How to link the two users so they can both view the same tables SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlplus, database-security

[image: [![]enter image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC7sw.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC7sw.jpg)I made my user with my tables etc. Then I created a new user with privileges but the tables are not there in the new user... how can I link the two users so both users can make use of the tables that they have access to?

I used 'Grant all on tablex to user2;' however, when I connect to user2, I am unable to view the table tales (this table x is on the User1 account). My question is how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Hint:  `GRANT` to give permissions for users to access objects.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, I used 'Grant all on tablex to user2;' however, when I connect to user2, I am unable to view the table tales (this table x is on the User1 account). My question is how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We aren't looking over your shoulder, but I'll bet a cookie that you are not qualifying the table name.

If you query like this:

```
select * from mytable;
```

oracle will only look in your own name space -- your own tables - for a table named MYTABLE.

If you want to see someone else's tables, you have to qualify with the owner name:

```
select * from otheruser.mytable;
```

If you don't want to qualify the name, you need to create a synonym in your own schema, pointing to the table in the other schema.

As USER2:

```
create synonym mytable on otheruser.mytable;
```

Comment: I altered the image in the question. But does your explanation still stand? Also, when i run the 'create synonym mytable on otheruser.mytable;' i get 'ORA-00905: missing keyword'

Comment: Your sketch changes nothing.  So you got an error on createing the synonym.  I was just writing it off the top of my head. Since it obviously has a syntax error, why don't you check the Oracle SQL Reference section on CREATE SYNONYM?  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401

Comment: It is not `on`, but `for`, i.e. `create synonym mytable FOR otheruser.mytable`